# Retrieve a list of records that are uncommited/pending

Tags: apex, callout

I am attempting to perform a callout using DocuSign's Apps Launcher managed package. Despite performing the callout in a Queuable, I am receiving the  error message "You have uncommitted work pending. Please commit or rollback before calling out."

After reviewing the debug logs, I found that the DML was occurring within the package and was attempting an upsert on the **dfsle__TokenSettings__c** object. While I was able to figure out the cause of the error using debug logs, I was wondering if there is a way to retrieve a list of all uncommitted work using Apex so that when this error does occur, I can create a custom log record detailing the issue.

Comment: No, there's no way to get a list of uncommitted work in Apex. There isn't even an easy, reliable way to tell if this exception would be thrown until it is.

Comment: Thanks for the quick response @sfdcfox!

Comment: @MeirH Did you figure out why DS is attempting this upsert and how to avoid?  I'm running into the same issue.

Comment: @JasonClark I can't say for certain why DS is attempting this but my guess is that it's related to an access token expiring. So DS needs to refresh the access token every so often and then store it in an object. My workaround was to use a try/catch, and when this particular error is hit, perform a retry. It seems to always work on the second try.